# Cycle for in firebase functions with querys

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

How can I get different nodes in firebase database and update them in a for cycle?
I have some issues like that function just update only one node or none.

```
exports.checkClassification = functions.https.onRequest((req,res) =>{

const eventID = req.query.eventid;

admin.database().ref("/OldEvents/" + eventID).on("value", function(snap){    
    eventMembers.forEach(member => {
        var userID = member.val();

        admin.database().ref("/Users/" + userID).on("value", function(snap){
            var totalEvents = snap.child("totalEvents").val();
            var totalEventsNew = totalEvents + 1 ;

            admin.database().ref("/Users/" + userID + "/total/").set(totalEventsNew );

        }, function(error){
            res.send("ERROR");
            console.error("ERROR1 " + error);
        });
    });
        res.send("OK");
}, function(error){
    res.send("ERROR");
    console.error("ERROR2 " + error);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're doing a ".on" reference inside of a ".on" reference.  I think you have to change the internal one to a ".once" reference.

Comment: I change the two functions to .once and it's working fine! Thank you!

Comment: Great! Glad to help! The .on is for streams so it gets a little tricky. If you don’t need realtime the .once are a bit easier sine it’s just a one time access.